# Problems in receiving data as a client in Python (TCP)

Tags: python, python-3.x, chat, serversocket

I have a little problem in my client chat app, basically the app crash if I try to do a function that receive data separately from the one that I use to send them.
Basically, if I have only this function it works:

```
def send_message (ip_address, port, message):
      #Connect to the server
      c = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
      c.connect((ip_address, port))
      #Convert message in bytes-like object
      message = message.encode("utf8")
      c.send(message)

      #Receive data
      data = c.recv(88888888888888)
      #Decode data from bytes-like object
      data = data.decode("utf8")
      return data
```

If I try to do two function, it doesn't work, like this:

```
def send_message (ip_address, port, message):
      #Connect to the server
      c = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
      c.connect((ip_address, port))
      #Convert message in bytes-like object
      message = message.encode("utf8")
      c.send(message)

def receive_message (ip_address, port, message):
      #Connect to the server
      c = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
      c.connect((ip_address, port))

      #Receive data
      data = c.recv(88888888888888)
      #Decode data from bytes-like object
      data = data.decode("utf8")
      return data
```

When I try to call the receive_message function from my GUI the app stop working. Hoping someone can help

EDIT: This is the server code:

```
import socket
import sys
from threading import Thread



def client_thread(conn, ip, port, MAX_BUFFER_SIZE = 4096):

# the input is in bytes, so decode it
input_from_client_bytes = conn.recv(MAX_BUFFER_SIZE)

# decode input and strip the end of line
input_from_client = input_from_client_bytes.decode("utf8").rstrip()

print("Result of processing is: {}".format(input_from_client))

vysl = res.encode("utf8")  # encode the result string
conn.sendall(vysl)  # send it to client
conn.close()  # close connection
print('Connection ' + ip + ':' + port + " ended")

def start_server():

import socket
soc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
# this is for easy starting/killing the app
soc.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
print('Socket created')

try:
    soc.bind(("127.0.0.1", 12345))
    print('Socket bind complete')
except socket.error as msg:
    import sys
    print('Bind failed. Error : ' + str(sys.exc_info()))
    sys.exit()

#Start listening on socket
soc.listen(10)
print('Socket now listening')

# for handling task in separate jobs we need threading
from threading import Thread

# this will make an infinite loop needed for 
# not reseting server for every client
while True:
    conn, addr = soc.accept()
    ip, port = str(addr[0]), str(addr[1])
    print('Accepting connection from ' + ip + ':' + port)
    try:
        Thread(target=client_thread, args=(conn, ip, port)).start()
    except:
        print("Terible error!")
        import traceback
        traceback.print_exc()
soc.close()

start_server()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49038141/chat-client-server-problems-on-python/49038188?noredirect=1#comment85083525_49038188 Here is the new question

Answer (score 0):

You don't show what's on the other end of your connection. I guess it's something like an `echo` which responds to received messages.

In the first case you open a single connection, first write to it, then read a response.

In the second case you open two separate connections. You write to the first one socket, read from the second one. Is anyone writing on the second socket? I guess not.

Comment: Sorry, I'm putting also the server code in the question, they are not in the right line in my answer but in the program yes

Comment: First, your server code is not valid Python - you lost indents. Second - my answer is exactly correct. Your client writes on one sockets, attempts to read on another. Since you never write anything on the second socket, the server does not respond, so the second socket blocks indefinitely on read.

Comment: Me and my class mate modified a lot the code, but there are still problems I'm opening a new topic