# Chat Client/Server problems on Python

Tags: python, sockets, server, client, chat

Me and a friend of mine are doing a chat room with python, basically he's doing the server part and I'm doing the GUI and Client part, I don't know why the app just stop to work without any reason showing the Windows message "Python is not responding"

This is the Server code:

```
#max name length=9999
#max message types=100
#max groupmsg recipients = 9999
#max msg length =8191 characters

import socket
import threading
import sys

def find_users(): #Continously Searches For New Clients
   while True:
      user, client_address = connector.accept()
      threading.Thread(target=new_user, args=(user,)).start()

def new_user(identity):
    while True:
       print(identity)
       name_length=identity.recv(4).decode() #max user name length =9999
       username=identity.recv(int(name_length)).decode()
       password=identity.recv(8192).decode()
       if username in user_details and password == user_details[username]: #correct credentials
          client_details[usename]=identity
          identity.sendall('y'.encode())
          break

       elif username in user_details: #incorrect password
          print('Please Re-enter The User Details')
          identity.sendall('n'.encode())

       else: #New user
            user_details[username]=password
            client_details[username]=identity
            identity.sendall('y'.encode())
            break

    pubmsg(username+' has connected')
    active_users.append(username)
    identity.settimeout(5)

    try:
       while True: #waits for incoming messages
           msgtype= identity.recv(2).decode() #identifies message type, max types =100

           if msgtype == '01': #public message
              communication = identity.recv(8192).decode()
              pubmsg(str(username + ' >>> ' + communication))

           elif msgtype == '02': #private message
              direction=[]
              recipno=identitiy.recv(4) #defines max group msg recipients
              for y in range(0,recipno): #repeats once per recipient
                 recip_name_length=identity.recv(4).decode()
                 recip_name=identity.recv(recip_name_length).decode()
                 direction.append(recip_name)

              gmsg=identity.recv(8192).decode()
              groupmsg(gmsg,direction)

    except Exception as e:
       active_users.remove(username)
       del client_details[username]
       pubmsg(username+' disconnected')
       identity.close()
       sys.exit()

def pubmsg(Group_message):
   print(Group_message)
   for person in client_details:
      client_details[person].sendall(Group_message.encode())

def groupmsg(Direct_message,recipients,sender):
    gmsg=sender +' (to '
    for person in recipients: #repeats once per recipient
        gmsg+=person+', '

    gmsg=gmsg.rstrip(', ')
    gmsg=gmsg + ')' + ' >>> ' + Direct_message

    for person in recipients:
        client_details[person].sendall(gmsg)

user_details={}
client_details={}
active_users=[]

connector = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
print ('Launching Server')
connector.bind(('localhost', 5000)) #Links socket to server address

connector.listen(10)
threading.Thread(target=find_users).start()
```

For the client and the GUI I'm putting here only the function called by the button "Connect" of the GUI (the ones that are creating problems), the GUI uses the QT Libraries

This is the code called by the button:

```
def client_connect(self):
        ip_address = str(self.ipText.toPlainText())
        port = int(self.portText.toPlainText())
        nickname = self.nameText.toPlainText()
        password = 'hello'

        connect = threading.Thread(target = connection_thread, args = (ip_address, port, nickname, password))
        connect.start()
```

This is the thread function:

```
def connection_thread(address, port, nickname, password):
        nickname = nickname.encode()
        password = password.encode()
        while True:
                try:
                        c = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                        c.connect((address, port))
                        c.sendall('{0:0=4d}'.format(len(nickname)).encode())
                        c.sendall(nickname)
                        c.sendall(password)
                        answr = c.recv(2).decode()
                        if answr == 'y':
                                msg_box("CONNECTED", "Now you are connected to the server.")
                                while True:
                                        time.sleep(2)
                                        c.sendall('03'.encode())
                                        message_received =c.recv(8192).decode()
                                        self.chatList.addItem(message_received)
                except Exception as e:
                        msg_box("CONNECTION FAILED", "Connection to server failed, try again.")
                        break
```

From the server code the connection of my client arrives but, the client stop working without showing the msg_box that says that we are connected.

Answer (score 0):

When you say `connect.join()` you wait for the thread `connect` to finish, but it is in an infinite loop, so it is not done until the connection closes.

Comment: So basically I should only delete it?

Comment: I deleted it but there is another problem, now it show first the msg_box that says connected and after two second the one with connection failed...